# How do I check if at least one descendant of the node have text content?

Tags: xslt

I have a XML that looks like

```
<xml>
    <grandparent>
        <parent>
            <child1/>
            <child2/>
            <child3>value</child3>
        </parent>
    </grandparent>
</xml>
```

I need to apply certain template if at least one descendant of parent has  value

After searching this site I came up with a code

```
<xsl:if test="grandparent/parent//* != '' ">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="parent"/>
</xsl:if>
```

But its not working. Nothing happens when I run this.
The apply-template by itself does work, so the problem is not the template
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"The apply-template by itself does work"*   I don't think so. There are no elements named `template1` in your XML. `

Comment: I didn't think template was important and didn't put it in the code. Sorry its my first question. Code edited now

Comment: Re your edited question: your test is not what I would use, but it WILL work, IF applied from the context of the root element `xml`. But then the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction will not do anything because `parent` is not a child of the current node. This is why it's so important to post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to apply certain template if at least one descendant of parent
>   has  value
>
> After searching this site I came up with a code
>
> ```
> <xsl:if test="grandparent/parent//* != '' ">
>     <xsl:apply-templates select="template1"/>
> </xsl:if>
> ```
>
> But its not working.

**Analysis**:

1. When templates are applied using the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction, one cannot specify any template name (and templates typically are not named). What the `select` attribute is expected to contain is an XPath expresion returning a node-set (a sequence in XSLT 3.0) with the nodes on which templates must be applied.
2. Therefore `select="template1"` means **not** apply the template named "template1", but apply templates to any child-element of the current node, named `template1` As there are no elements named `template1` in the provided XML document, nothing is selected and nothing is applied templates on. This explains the reported behavior

You may want to use `<xsl:call-template name="template1">` but calling named templates is generally not a good practice in XSLT.

Also, you haven't specified what is the current node when templates should be applied or called.

**Solution**:

Let's assume the current node is the top node in the XML document.

Below is a transformation that still uses `<xsl:apply-templates>` but only specifies a template mode to be used by the XSLT processor when selecting the template to be executed:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="grandparent">
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="template1" select="parent[*//text()]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parent" mode="template1">
    Template in mode template1 Applied
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:

```
<xml>
    <grandparent>
        <parent>
            <child1/>
            <child2/>
            <child3>value</child3>
        </parent>
    </grandparent>
</xml>
```

the wanted result (showing the template was selected for execution and executed) is produced:

```
Template in mode template1 Applied
```

Let's now test this with a modified XML document in which no children of `grandparent/parent` has a text-node child:

```
<xml>
    <grandparent>
        <parent>
            <child1/>
            <child2/>
            <child3></child3>
        </parent>
    </grandparent>
</xml>
```

When we apply the same transformation on this XML document, no output is produced -- exactly as wanted.

Comment: I'm sorry my question was misinforming. I didn't think template mattered. The code should be 
<xsl:if test="grandparent/parent//* != '' ">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="parent"/>
</xsl:if>

Comment: @SvetaS: The solution now reflects this clarification. Thanks.